# Wordpress - plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am fairly new to wordpress but i am trying to modify a template, basically if you visit the website you will see that underneath the menu there is a news in pictures box (black with a grey image and text) now basically i want to replace that box with a nivo slider.  I have installed the simple nivo slider plugin in to the website.  However the template doesn't have a widget area for the area i want to change and i don't know how to swap one for the other.

```
  http://79.170.40.241/shaddersafrica.com/
```

on the main index.php page this piece of code controls the news in pictures box.

```
<?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/latest-post.php' ); ?>
```

now i have tried to replace this with a link to the simple-nivo-slider plugin, like so

```
<?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '../../plugins/simple-nivo-slider/simple-nico-slider.php' ); ?>
```

however when i do this nothing is displayed.

Thanks

Lee

Comment: This website is for programming-related questions. For those kind of issues you should try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. Also, that is not the way plugins work. You should check the plugin documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I choose simple way to add [WordPress slideshow plugin](http://www.cincopa.com/media-platform/wordpress-plugin/slideshow) or video plugin. Search for cincopa plugin in widgets area. You can easily embed any kind of media plugin using shortcode. You can store images and videos in Cincopa as well.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin should come with a shortcode that you can simply enter via the main wordpress WYSIYYG editor.